# structure definition and initialisation

Tags: c, structure

I've a structure like this

```
typedef struct mystruct{
    char* name;
    int age : 5;
}instr;

int main(){
    instr object1={.name= "tiny",.age=20};
    printf("%d and %d\n",object1.age);
    return 0;
}
```

what is the meaning of the line
**int age : 5** in the stucture definition?

For lower values, instead of 5 here, I get compilation warning

> overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signed 5-bit integer (as defined by your `int age : 5;` bit-field) can hold values in the range -16 .. +15, but 20 is outside this range.

Use `unsigned int` or use 6 or more bits.  Actually, people can be old enough to need 7 bits unsigned or 8 bits signed.

Bit-fields are curious parts of the language.  I doubt if you will benefit from using one for age as here.  You might use a `char` value of some sort, though you won't be wasting space in the structure even if you use an `int` (it will have a size of 8 bytes on 32-bit machines, and probably 16 bytes on 64-bit machines).

In ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §6.7.2.1 **Struct and union specifiers**, footnote 125 says:

> <sup>125)</sup> As specified in 6.7.2 above, if the actual type specifier used is `int` or a typedef-name defined as `int`,
>   then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned.

It appears from the warning message you got that plain `int` bit-fields with your compiler are signed.  You should be explicit about whether you want the type to be `signed int` or `unsigned int`.

Comment: in other words what comes after the colon it's about a `bitfield width` :D

Comment: @user2485710: you're right — and I've added information from the standard about bit fields.

Comment: found and interesting tutorial for newbies like me.
[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm)

Comment: Not a bad little tutorial.  It's a bit spartan on the caveats that should be associated with bit-fields (portability, order, footnote 125, etc), but it covers the basics sufficiently to give you a passing idea what you're dealing with.  Explore the main example there with the variant structure: `struct
    {
      unsigned int widthValidated : 1;
      unsigned : 0;
      unsigned int heightValidated : 1;
    } status2;` and see what result you get.  On my Mac, it makes both structures of size 8 (64-bit compilation).

Comment: with gcc-4.7 (ubuntu 13.10 - 32 bit) answer is as expected.

Comment: anybody wants to comment on this link ? [link](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BitField)

or this statement. 
**Note that signed bit-fields might not even be able to contain -1, this is true in computers that use 1-complement for representing signed int's. A signed bit-field that can contain 1 is a bug in the compiler.**

Comment: The link begins to delve into some of the mysteries of bit-fields. The comment about 'signed bit-fields might not even be able to contain `-1`' is accurate for signed single-bit bit-fields; you can have zero, and you can have the most significant bit set, but there isn't really a value. So, you have to be extremely cautious. Normally, aim to use `unsigned name : 1` rather than either `int name : 1`; for larger bit-fields (size 2 or more), you can use `signed` if you wish. (I've been coding in C a long time and never needed to use bit-fields. If you can, you should aim not to use them either.)

Comment: @user1725216 my suggestion is to start with bitfields if and only if you find it useful for you, keep in mind that bitfields are not portable and since they basically are a chunk of bits, you need a solid background in binary operations and binary arithmetic; in short they are a really special solution and you should think twice before adopting them, they are likely to not to be what you want or what can solve your problems. If you want to speed-up things with some really low level operations maybe you should take a look at the intrinsics that are a much better solution and quite portable too.